# Javascript TypeError: undefined is not a function when initializing an instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting a JS `TypeError: undefined is not a function` when trying to create an instance of a schema I define and import.

**article.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Article Schema
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title    : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    author   : { type: String, required: true },
    day      : { type: String, required: true },
    month    : { type: String, required: true },
    year     : { type: String, required: true },
    link     : { type: String, required: true },
    password : { type: String, required: false, select: false }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);
```

**api.js**

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");    // get body-parser
var article    = require("../models/article");
var config     = require("../../config");

module.exports = function(app, express) {

    var apiRouter = express.Router();

    // Some stuff

    var article = new article();     // create a new instance of the article model

    // ...
```

The error is being thrown when the api tries to create the new Article, here is a screenshot of the full error:

[image: TypeError]

The line 34:34 is when I try to initiate the new article.

I am aware this question gets asked all the time, and I'm sorry if the error is incredibly stupid but I went through 20 different "TypeError: undefined" questions, trying different things inside and I could not for the life of me fix it.

Comment: try `var myArticle = new article();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring a variable called "article". That's the same name you used for the module you imported, so your local variable will hide the more global one. Variables start off with no value, so they're `undefined`.

If you change the local variable name, then assuming your export is set up correctly you will be able to access the constructor.

Comment: That absolutely was it. I'm extremely sorry for the very dumb question, I kinda thought that might be it a split second before you answered. 

Thanks for elaborating in terms of the scope.

Answer (score 3):

Use a different name: If you do `var article` you overwrite the initial `var article` and thus it doesn't work.

Good practice is to use uppercase for the ModelNames:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");    // get body-parser
var Article    = require("../models/article");
var config     = require("../../config");

module.exports = function(app, express) {

var apiRouter = express.Router();

// Some stuff

var article = new Article();     // create a new instance of the article model

// ...
```

Try it like this, should work now :)

Comment: Absolutely did. Thanks for mentioning the good practice. I had seen a couple of people do it that way but now I painfully understand why that is.